# Script closes after running immediately and the Read-Host -Prompt does not work

Tags: powershell

I have made a PowerShell script that finds the password for your network, however it immediately closes after opening. I tried using the Read-Host command yet it doesn't work. Here is my script:

```
$Output = netsh wlan show profiles name="enter network here" key=clear
$SSIDSearchResults = $Output | Select-String -Pattern 'SSID Name'
$ProfileName = ($SSIDSearchResults -split ":")[-1].Trim() -replace '"'
$PwSearchResult = $Output | Select-String 'Key Content'
$PW = ($PwSearchResult -split ":")[-1].Trim() -replace '"'
[pscustomobject] @{
        WifiProfileName = $ProfileName 
        Password = $PW 

}
```

Comment: Hi, do you use the ISE to write PowerShell code ? hit **start**, type in **ise** and hit **enter**.

Comment: Yes I Use PowerShell ISE. All my problems have been reaolved

Comment: The way you mark a question as answered is by using the check mark next to the answer that helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're calling powershell from another location you might use `-noexit` to keep it from closing at least to debug.

only slightly unrelated to your question, here is a simple way you could make it into a function

```
function Show-WifiPassword ($network) {
    $Output = netsh wlan show profiles name="$network" key=clear
    $SSIDSearchResults = $Output | Select-String -Pattern 'SSID Name'
    $ProfileName = ($SSIDSearchResults -split ":")[-1].Trim() -replace '"'
    $PwSearchResult = $Output | Select-String 'Key Content'
    $PW = ($PwSearchResult -split ':')[-1].Trim() -replace '"'
    [pscustomobject] @{
        WifiProfileName = $ProfileName 
        Password = $PW 
    }
}
```

and here is the one i use. admittedly, it could be more readable, but i like that it is a one-liner

```
function Show-WifiPasswords {
    netsh wlan show profiles | ? {$_ -match ' : '} | % {$_.split(':')[1].trim()} | % {$n = $_; netsh wlan show profile name="$_" key=clear} | ? {$_ -match 'key content'} | select @{n='Network';e={$n}}, @{n='Key';e={$_.split(':')[1].trim()}}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the version you use works, however the one above doesn't. I prefer the one liner anyways

Comment: I have encountered a small problem. It appears that for network keys above 11 characters it doesn't show the full key, is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: You might have to just run the netsh command by itself to see if it is a limitation of that program

Comment: It works now. I don't know why it wouldn't show the full key however after a Windows update it worked perfectly fine